# Exporting VRM model from Blender, getting multiple Python errors?

Tags: modeling, python

I haven't ever before until today. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or what but I'm continuously getting Python errors when I try and export my model from the CATS menu. Is there an easy fix to this that I simply can't figure out because I can't read Python? Here are some of the errors I get:

```py
Python: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\(my name)\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\cats-blender-plugin-master\tools\importer.py", line 880, in execute bpy.ops.cats_importer.display_error('INVOKE DEFAULT')
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 130, in_call_ret=_op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo
RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "C:\Users]\(my name)\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\cats-blender-plugin-master\tools\importer.py", line 966, in invoke return context window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=dpi_value*6.1)
   TypeError: WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog():error with keyboard argument "width" - Function.width expected an int type, not float
   location D:\Program Files(x86)\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:130
   location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Blender 3.1, it's probably because Blender now uses Python 3.10 and that no longer allows implicit down conversion from float to int. You can find out more in they Blender 3.1 [Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.1/Python_API).

You need to update the exporter to fix the bug. The [CATS](https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin) developers have a discord channel you can contact them on to make them aware of the bug.